# How to get search input in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

This are DataTables https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/23922/assign-an-id-to-the-search-input

I have an implementation in Vue3 project but I am not able to fix some I mean bugs in there. It should be simple but I am not able to get any dynamically generated elements in there. For example needs to add class to the search input.
According the link I mentioned above the code I use looks like

```
    setDataTable() {
        var table = $('#myTable');

        if( this.dataTableObject ) return this.dataTableObject.draw();

        this.dataTableObject = table.DataTable({
            'responsive': true,
            "pageLength": 10,
            ...
        });


        // Both selectors are empty. 
        $('.dataTables_wrapper').find('input');  
    }
```

Before the code I import the required libraries

```
import "datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css"
import 'datatables.net-bs4'
```

But selector is empty. Hope somebody will know cause I spend the whole day on it without any success. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add your complete code?

Comment: There is little more code.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based on draw event.

```
this.dataTableObject.on('draw', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.dataTables_wrapper')
        .removeClass('form-inline')
        .find('.col-xs-12').addClass('col-12');
});
```

DataTables forum says that I have old DTBootstrap4 version. So I am curious what they answer in the question I asked them. Cause this is really dirty code.

Answer (score 0):

this element is easyly editable, I've added 'style="background: green"' for the input search ant it worked.

Try to set property by property using:

```
document.getElementById("p2").style.color="blue";
```

Or try change entire class using:

```
document.getElementById("p2").className = "classname";
```

Comment: So why you thing the code $('.dataTables_filter input').addClass( 'form-control' ); does not work?

Comment: It depends how the project is structured, the rest of codes above work for you?

I recommend you make a minimal test to check this.

Comment: Ok thanks. Today minimal means vue, webpack, bundlers, modules, ..... Its like 10 years ago. Code it still more and more complicated. I have a solution but it looks really bad.